# Multi-project gradle build with Nexus artifact repository

Tags: gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, nexus, dependency-management

Consider the following multi-project gradle build, where ProjectA depends on ProjectB, and ProjectB depends on ProjectC. Dependencies are specified in the form `compile project(':ProjectX')`. This requires that each project be checked out in order to build, say, ProjectA.

I want to use an artifact repo such as Sonatype Nexus, to make the build simpler for developers so that if they are only working on ProjectA, then they do not need to have the dependent projects checked out, and they can be retrieved from Nexus. Similarly, if you are working on the dependent projects and they are checked out locally, I want them to be build instead of being retrieved from Nexus.

In summary, the dependency resolution strategy is: If project dependency and checked out, build locally, else retrieve from Nexus

How can I achieve this in gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by flipping my dependency definitions from `compile project(':ProjectX')` to `compile "my-group:ProjectX:version"`, and use the following dependency substitution resolution strategy:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution.all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
        if (dependency.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && dependency.requested.group == "my-group") {
            def proj = "${dependency.requested.module}"
            if (new File(rootDir, '../' + proj).exists()) {
                dependency.useTarget findProject(":${proj}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Composit builds may help. It is the same idea in your answer. It is also supported by many IDEs.

Comment: Here is the link. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html